# How can I replace characters AND numbers at the same time?

Tags: jquery, regex, character, replace

I have a string that looks like - `/celebrity.html#portfolios/jennifer-aniston-2006#img10`

I want to remove #img10 (which can also be #img6; any number really).

I have used this code:

```
var docLoc = document.location.href.replace("#img", '');
var docLoc2= docLoc.replace(/[0-9]+/,'');
```

When I log *docLoc2*, I get `/celebrity.html#portfolios/jennifer-aniston-`

I really want to combine these two replace functions, so it does it all at once, and therefore will only remove #img10. I have also written this:

```
var docLoc = document.location.href.replace("#img"+/[0-9]+/, '');
```

This doesn't work (I think the syntax is wrong).

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
var docLoc = document.location.href.replace(/#img[0-9]+$/, '');
```

---

[`.replace` <sup>MDN documentation</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) works with either a string or a regular expression. You tried to combine both with the wrong syntax as you noted yourself...

Comment: Maybe `/#img[0-9]+$/` to make sure it's at the end of the string... (if that is a requirement)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex could be this

```
#img\d*
```